# Orchard CMS Update Common_BodyPartRecord table

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I need to make some text changes to over 100 blog posts migrated from a Wordpress site. I was going to do this via SQL to update rows in the Common_BodyPartRecord table.

When I update the rows the changes are not reflected in the front end. I understand Orchard uses NHibernate, is there some sort of caching I am not aware of?

I know that you are advised to not mess about in the database, so is there a better way to do some bulk text manipulation? If necessary I can generate an Orchard module and do this via a database migration.

NB All blog posts are latest and published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly caching per se, it's that the body part is also stored on the Infoset, which is a blob of XML that you can find on the content item records. You need to change both.

Comment: I looked at `Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord` and can see the `Text='blah'` in it. Thanks Bertrand. PS kudos to you for all the help you provide for Orchard here.

Comment: Infoset is stored in the `Data` column of `Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord` or `Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord` tables. See here: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/the-shift-how-orchard-painlessly-shifted-to-document-storage-and-how-it-ll-affect-you